# How to iterate through possible null values in javascript without errors

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have up to 100 inputs on my screen, each one has either a numerical value, or is null (as its not been loaded onto the screen yet), I want to be able to take the value's of each of these inputs, and add them together to get a final value.

I have attempted this with a for loop, iterating through them, but once it gets to the null value ones, it returns 'NaN' error.

The first input is called 'Input1', the second 'Input2' etc...

My code below:

```
    var val = 0;  //assigning the final value OUTSIDE the for loop to stop it assigning itself as 0 every loop

    for (var calc = 0; calc < 100; calc++) //less than 100 as of 100 inputs
    {
        var inputVal = $('#Input'+calc).val(); //grabbing each input on screen
        var floatVal = parseFloat(inputVal);  // converting each value to float

        var finalVal = finalValue + floatVal; //takes the val of 0, and adds each input value onto it per loop

    }

    alert(finalVal);
```

This always returns 'NaN'.

If I set the for loop to 'calc < 2' for example, and load 2 inputs on the screen, it will work, so I'm assuming its because the other values are null?

Thank you

Comment: null is false: var floatVal = (inputVal) ? parseFloat(inputVal) : 0;

Comment: So just add a condition before add the value. Check if the value is null and if so, put a continue statement to skip executing javascript for that loop item and to jump next value. Simply do this ----> if (inputVal === undefined) continue; // put all the calculation code below this.

Comment: hey @anthony you can just add a check if input[calc] != null then only add else log something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Number.isNaN(value)` function to skip to the next loop iteration if the value is `NaN`.

Noticed in your code you declare `val` but then never use it, instead you declare a new `finalVal` on every loop. You should declare `finalVal` before the loop and add to it on every iteration, as such:

```js
var finalVal = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var inputVal = $('#Input'+i).val();
    var floatVal = parseFloat(inputVal);
    if (Number.isNaN(floatVal)) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    finalVal += floatVal;
}
alert(finalVal);
```

Comment: Sadly Number.isNaN(null) is false

Comment: @netizen The value being passed to `isNaN` is not `null` though. It would be `NaN`, as this is what `parseFloat(null)` returns. Try running `Number.isNaN(parseFloat(null))` in your console.

Comment: @netizen Well you'll be surprised to know, the original code posted worked a treat! it now tallies up everything, ignoring the NaN values.